# How to remove character after specific character?

Tags: java, string, character

**I have for example this string:**

> hello.name-2.txt

And I need to remove only character after "-".

**So my output should look:**

> hello.name-.txt

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
s = s.replaceAll("-.", "-");
```

if you want to replace a number even "hello.name-1234.txt" you can use

```
s = s.replaceAll("-\\d+", "-");
```

If you only want to do this once, you can use `replaceFirst` instead.

Comment: great, I will accept your answer in five minutes, I can't accept it now ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
 int dashIndex = yourString.indexOf("-");
 String result = yourString.substring(0, dashIndex + 1) 
               + yourString.substring(dashIndex + 2);
```